# number in worksheet name as "any number"

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code:

```
Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook
wb2.Worksheets("-Incumbents").Range("B2:C2", Range("B2:C2").End(xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header _
:=xlYes
wb2.Worksheets("-Incumbents").Range("B2:C2", Range("B2:C2").End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
```

I would like it to work on any worksheet which name contains word "-Incumbents".
The problem is that worksheets are named "1-Incumbents","2-Incumbents","3-Incumbents" and so on...
So I guess I need some kind of variable to put in the code instead of actual number, but I can't figure out how to do that.
Please help.

Comment: Loop through the worksheets and test whether the sheet name is `Like "*-Incumbents"` if so do your code.

Comment: Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook
For Each ws In wb2
If ws.Name Like "*-Incumbents" Then Worksheet.Activate

wb2.ActiveSheet.Range("B2:C2", Range("B2:C2").End(xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header _
:=xlYes
wb2.ActiveSheet.Range("B2:C2", Range("B2:C2").End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Next ws

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim wb2 as Workbook
Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook
For Each ws in wb2.worksheets
    If ws.Name Like "*-Incumbents" Then
        wb2.Worksheets("-Incumbents").Range("B2:C2", Range("B2:C2").End _
          (xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header _
          :=xlYes
        wb2.Worksheets("-Incumbents").Range("B2:C2", Range("B2:C2").End _
          (xlDown)).Select
        Selection.Copy
     End If
Next
```

Comment: change `wb2.Worksheets("-Incumbents").` to `ws.`

Comment: I've came up with something similar ( as you may see in my comment above - didn't know how to paste it as code sample in comment :) ) But it was not working, now I know why :) Thank you

Comment: As mentioned in the other answer, there's no need for the `Select` followed by `Selection.Copy`. Just replace `.Select` with `.Copy`.

Answer (score 3):

As Scott Craner said, first, have a loop through all your sheets.
Second, compare the sheet.name with "Incumbents", you can either use the "`Like`" or "`InStr`" functions:

```
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook

For Each sht In wb2.Sheets

    ' option 1: use Like
    If sht.Name Like "Incumbents" Then

    ' option 2: use Instr
    ' If InStr(1, sht.Name, "Incumbents") > 0 Then
        sht.Range("B2:C2", sht.Range("B2:C2").End(xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header _
        :=xlYes
        sht.Range("B2:C2", sht.Range("B2:C2").End(xlDown)).Copy
    End If

Next sht
```

Comment: Also, there's no need for the `Select` followed by `Selection.Copy`. Just replace `.Select` with `.Copy`.

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks all of you